# Mail Server Not Receiving Email But Sending it Fine

Tags: email, dns, plesk, nameservers, horde

I am using Plesk Parallel mailbox using web bases Horde.  I can send email but it is unable to receive email. My other email account (gmail) never complains about such as unable to deliver or recipient does not exist.  I am assuming it is DNS issue where receiving mail is not directed to my Horde inbox (in webmail.exampledomain.com).

I have following DNS entries on my server which also act as my primary nameserver.

```
     Host
     mail.exampledomain.com   

     Record type
     A

     Value
     ipaddress (111.222.111.222)
```

Am I missing any primary name server records for incoming mail to this server?

**Update:**

I am getting following error on gmail when I send an email to my server valid email accounts:

```
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=7720
[(10) mail.exampledomain.com. [ipaddress]:25: Connection refused]
```

Comment: do you have an MX record in your zone?

Comment: I have following MX record: Host=exampledomain.com. Record Type=MX (10) Value=mail.exampledomain.com.

Comment: "Connection refused" is what you get when mail server doesn't listen to the port/interface on which the connection was attempted, or access is blocked by firewall.

Comment: @Bushmills how would I go about checking if mail server is not running or firewall is blocking it? I am on Centos 5.5. Help pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: check whether running and what addresses/ports it bimds to: netstat -tunlp    -   check firewall:  iptables -nvL - you'd run thar on mail.exampledomain.com, and assumes that machine is under iinux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason incoming mail was not delivered because I had popmail service was disabled. I enabled and it worked fine.